# DFA with an accepting state in the initial state

Tags: computer-science, automata

I have this diagram of a DFA:

[image: webber-ch2-6c.png]

I have written that DFA as 5-tuple $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F )$ where:

- $Q$ is the set of all states: $Q = \left \{ q_0, q_1, q_2\right \}$;
- $\Sigma$ is the alphabet: $\Sigma = \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}$;
- $\delta$ is the transition function;
- $q_0$ is the initial state;
- $F$ is the set of final states: $F = \left\{ q_0, q_2\right \}$.

and I have written the transition function $\delta$:

$\begin{array}{rcl}\delta(q_0, 0) & = & q_1 \\ \delta(q_0, 1) & = & q_2 \\ \delta(q_1, 0) & = & q_1 \\ \delta(q_1, 1) & = & q_1 \\ \delta(q_2, 0) & = & q_2 \\ \delta(q_2, 1) & = & q_2 \end{array}$

therefore I understand that:
- if the DFA is in state $q_0$ and reads symbol $0$, $0$ will be rejected;
- if the DFA is in state $q_0$ and reads symbol $1$, $1$ will be accepted.

but what I don't understand is:

what's the meaning of that accepting state in $q_0$?
Does it mean that, if the input is an empty string $\epsilon$, then, that empty string will be accepted and the DFA stops?

Please, can you explain me better? Many thanks!

Comment: It always starts at $q_0$. If all the input is read in and it's in the state $q_0$, then it'll accept the input. :) I.e. empty input is accepted.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! So, you have also explained a general case, in the first part of your answer. In this example, "all input" you said, it is the unique input formed only by empty string $\epsilon$. - Instead, considering this DFA: https://s26.postimg.org/9ad5hg0rd/automa_start_finish.png, here, it is valid both the empty string alone, and a string as "0110".

Comment: What you linked will accept a string iff it has an even number of $1$s in it. That includes both the empty string and "0110".

Comment: it will accept therefore string as, $\epsilon, 011, 0110$ etc...

Comment: Yeah, trace out the path on the graph a few times, and you'll get the hang of it! "" means stay, end program. $1$ means move along the edge labeled $1$, $0$ means move along the edge labeled $0$. :)

Comment: @Andrew Why don't you have put the first sentence you wrote as answer? With that, you have answered me exactly to what I want!

Comment: I'll do so, if you feel that way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The machine always starts at $q_0$. If all of the input string is read, and it's in the state $q_0$, then it'll accept the input. That is, the empty input in this case will also be accepted!